# How statement 3 is false and 4 true

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, instanceof

```
class Vehical{}

public class Car extends Vehical {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Vehical v = new Vehical();
        Car c = new Car();

        boolean is =  v instanceof Vehical;
        System.out.println("is v instanceof Vehical class - "+is);

        is = c instanceof Car;
        System.out.println("is c instanceof of Car class - "+is);

        is = v instanceof Car;
        System.out.println("is v instanceof of Car class - "+is);

        is = c instanceof Vehical;
        System.out.println("is c instanceof of Vehical class - "+is);
    }
}
```

Comment: All `Car`s are `Vehical`s. Not all `Vehical`s are `Car`s.

Comment: `Car`extends `Vehical`, `Vehical`doesn't  extends `Car`

Comment: What did you expect and why?

Comment: Sidenote, it's spelled Vehicle, not Vehical.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, that's the opposite

Comment: @jhamon Need more coffee.

Comment: *Vehicles include wagons, bicycles, motor vehicles (motorcycles, cars, trucks, buses), railed vehicles (trains, trams), watercraft (ships, boats), amphibious vehicles (screw-propelled vehicle, hovercraft), aircraft (airplanes, helicopters) and spacecraft.* (wiki) Define more subclasses and you will see `v instanceof Car` doesn't always hold true

Answer (score 1):

3. `Vehicle` isn't a `Car` because it is parent for a `Car`.
4. `Car` is implementation of `Vehicle`, so Car is Vehicle.

You can read more here:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-is-Is-a-relationship-in-Java

Answer (score 1):

Because `v` is a (concrete) `Vehical` (I think you mean vehicle).

But a 'concrete' instance of `Vehical` isn't a `Car`. It's a (non-specific) instance of `Vehical`. So `v instanceof Car` is `false`.

But `c` is a concrete instance of `Car` and because `Car` a sub-class of `Vehical` `c` is also a `Vehical` because all instances of `Car` are also instances of `Vehical`. So `c instanceof Vehical` is `true` because (in your model) all 'Car's are `Vehical's as well (implicitly by inheritance).

You can make `Vehical` an abstract class if you don't want instances of `Vehical` to exist that are not a more specific type of `Vehical` (e.g. `Car`, `Motorbike`?, `Lorry`?). In the real world there could never be a vehicle that isn't a specific kind of vehicle.

**Nonsense:** *What do you drive? I drive a vehicle. What kind of vehicle? No particular kind, it's just a vehicle!*

The recommended model would be to declare an `interface` called `Vehical` and implement it for each (more) concrete type of `Vehical` because this inheritance model can difficult to manage. But what you've done is valid.